# are there any relationships between socket and http,if yes,what are they?

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

are there any relationships between socket and http,if yes,what are they?

i know the http is one of the communication protocal in  Application Layer,and socket is used to build the connection between the application layer and transfer layer.But,i’m puzzled the relationship between them,such as,who serves who,or maybe who has packing who,and which layer does socket work in。

appreciate for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A socket is an endpoint of a TCP connection (or other things)' and HTTP is layered over TCP.